# SQL CLR Error, or Bug?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clr, sqlclr

I'm running some C# code inside of a CLR Function and running into some strange behavior.

When the following code runs:

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Vertica_GetVerticaServer_vw WHERE verticaServer IS NOT NULL ORDER BY NEWID()";

  using (cmd.Connection = GetSQLConnection())
  {
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (r.Read())
    {
      return r.GetString(0);
    }
  }
```

This error is thrown (full relevant stack trace below):

Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

However, when I run the same code, minus the "ORDER BY NEWID()" (used to randomize the result) and instead run the "ORDER BY NEWID()" inside of the view, I get no errors:  Anyone know what's going on here?

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Vertica_GetVerticaServer_vw WHERE verticaServer IS NOT NULL");// ORDER BY NEWID()";

  using (cmd.Connection = GetSQLConnection())
  {
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (r.Read())
    {
      return r.GetString(0);
    }
  }
  throw new Exception("Could not get Vertica Server name");
```

Seems like a bug, but maybe I'm missing something about the NEWID()?

(Note, I tested with GETDATE() instead to see if it was an issue with determinism, and it also worked...).

Full Stack Trace:

---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.InternalNextResult(Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.NextResult()
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderSmi(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
  at Aggregation.AggregateDataManager.GetVerticaServer()

As requested, here's the setup of the CLR TVF:

```
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRowAggregates", TableDefinition = "listId int, pricingDate datetime, value decimal", DataAccess=DataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static IEnumerable CalculateListAggregatePricing(int listId, DateTime start, DateTime end, int WeightTypeId)
    {
        DataRequest d = new DataRequest();
        d.Start = start;
        d.Finish = end;
        d.Metric = Metric.GetSharePricingMetric();
        d.Metric.Weight = WeightType.Equal;
        _listId = listId; 
        List<ConstituentInfo> ci = new List<ConstituentInfo>();
        foreach (int i in AggregateDataManager.GetConstituents(listId))
            ci.Add(new ConstituentInfo(i, end));

        switch (WeightTypeId)
        {
            case 0:
                EqualWeightInterpreterForSQLCLR e = new EqualWeightInterpreterForSQLCLR();
                return e.GetIndex(d, ci, false);
            case 1:
                MarketCapWeightInterpreterForSQLCLR mc = new MarketCapWeightInterpreterForSQLCLR();
                return mc.GetIndex(d, ci, false);
            case 2:
                PriceWeightInterpreterForSQLCLR p = new PriceWeightInterpreterForSQLCLR();
                return p.GetIndex(d, ci, false);
        }
        throw new Exception("Invalid Weight Type");

    }

    public static void FillRowAggregates(Object o, out SqlInt32 listId, out SqlDateTime pricingDate, out SqlDecimal value)
    {
        DataPoint dp = (DataPoint)o;

        listId = _listId;
        pricingDate = dp.PricingDate;
        value = (SqlDecimal)dp.Value;
    }
```

The connection is built by the WeightedInterpreters.

Comment: What is the complete code example for the CLR function and how its being used. If this is supposed to be a TVF, you have to provide the enumerable and the FillRow method, which are not above. If this is your exact use of SQLCLR, why?  This has been proven to be slower than using TSQL alone for this.

Comment: Does `GetSQLConnection` use a context connection string? I.e., `return new SqlConnection("context connection=true");`.

Comment: @Johnathan Yes, it's a TVF, I'll edit provide the functions.  The function actually reaches out to a separate DBMS (Vertica) to retrieve data and then does some complex aggregation that is MUCH slower in TSQL.

Comment: If your View definition is `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY NEWID()` then this will be optimised out.

Comment: @Martin - The top 100 percent will, but the randomization caused by the ORDER BY NEWID() will not.

Comment: @ElHombre - Nope. The whole thing will be ignored. Try `Use tempdb GO CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM master..spt_values ORDER BY NEWID() GO SELECT * FROM v` and look at the actual execution plan. There is no sort. The first row returned will be the `rpc` one.

Comment: @Martin Ahh.  It's the TOP 100 PERCENT that get's it optimized out.  I'm using TOP 1000 since there's only 6 rows in the underlying table and I get randomized results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like TOP 99.99999 PERCENT?